# Dynamically resizing image chopped in parts

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a mobile application using jquery mobile. I am looking for a solution to accomplish the following:

A large image is divided in three seperate clickable images

[image: example]

The images have to look like one big image at all times but have to resize to all available space while keeping the width/height ratio.

Has anyone done something like this before?

I have tried using a table and using the jquery mobile "content grids" without success.

Comment: Easiest way would probably be to actually save these 3 images as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd save the images as one image an use the following - working fiddle link at the bottom.
You can change "low_starts_here" and "right_starts_here" to fit your needs.
Also you can switch to "width:auto;height:100%" in the css, if that's better for you.

html:

```
<img src="/myimage.jpg" id="myimage" />
```

css:

```
#myimage{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;    
}
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {    
    $('#myimage').on('click', function(e){
        var area = '';
        var low_starts_here = 0.6;
        var right_starts_here = 0.5;
        var x = Math.round(e.pageX - $(this).offset().left);
        var y = Math.round(e.pageY - $(this).offset().top);
        var w = $(this).width();
        var h = $(this).height();
        if(y/h > low_starts_here){
            // bottom area - do something
            alert('bottom');
        }
        else{
            if(x/w > right_starts_here){
               // top right area - do something
               alert('top right');
            }
           else{
               // top left area - do something
               alert('top left');
            }
        }

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uLHhQ/6/

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to work out an example :) works like a charm.